# Bing Tranlate: ArgumentException: Invalid appId...

Tags: json, php

Есть код работы с АПИ бинг переводчиком, но время от времени он выкидывает вот такую ошибку:

> `ArgumentException: Invalid appId\u000d\u000aParameter name: appId : ID=3641.V2_Json.Translate.3638F001`

Может кто работал с ним, подскажите чем решается? Код не выкладываю, т.к не в нем дело. После обновления, например, проходит... Уже делаю 10 попыток перевода с таймаутами, но все равно. (((

Answer (score 1):

Нашел..
Apiid теперь устаревшая авторизация, они ввели authtoken ((